# Permutation from left to right of $140$ objects

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time now, I can't seem to find a video or such where it references permutations in a specific order of left to right. I have no idea how to set this problem up in terms of a formula.

> You have $140$ distinct food products, $80$ cans of soup, $20$ cereals and $40$ cookies. Assume that all $140$ products are different. In how many ways can you put the $140$ products on a shelf with the cans of soup on the left, cereal in the middle and cookies on the right?

If possible, can these two answers be verified? They're simple I know, but I always second guess myself when it comes to any form of math.

How many ways can you put $140$ products on the shelf? $140!$

In how many ways can you give away 10 products? $\frac{150!}{(150-10)!} = \frac{150!}{140!}$

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You are correct that $140$ distinct items can be arranged on the shelf in $140!$ ways.  However, the number of ways of giving away $10$ of the $140$ products is $$\binom{140}{10} = \frac{140!}{10!(140 - 10)!} = \frac{140!}{10!130!}$$  When you are selecting a subset, you should use [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).  [Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) are used for arrangements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we need to think of them as three separate permutations.

How many ways to arrange the soups? $80!$

For any given arrangement of soups how many ways to arrange the cereal? $20!$

For any given arrangement of soup and cereal how many ways to arrange cookies? $40!$

So, we multiply to get $80!20!40!$

In general, if the $n$  sub-arrangements are independent (which they are here - left, middle and right can't get mixed up), we have to multiply the permutations $P_1*P_2*P_3...P_{n-1}*P_n$

In this case $P_1*P_2*P_3=80!*20!*40!$

Answer (score 3):

There are $80!$ ways to arrange the soups, $20!$ for the cereal, $40!$ for the cookies. So in total $80!20!40!$ valid orders.

Comment: Thank you for your help, is there a specific formula or a way to figure out the number of ways regarding the position of those items that must be on the left,middle or right?